# Vue: Pass parent data to child when updated with button click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to Vue and trying to pass data from a parent component to the child when the parent data is updated via button click. The parent data is being updated, but the updated data is not being passed onto the child.

My main `App.vue` file is fairly standard:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <parent></parent>
  </div>
</template>


<script>

import parent from './components/parent.vue';
export default {
  components: {
    'parent':parent
  },
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The parent component has a button click to update the data and the change is displayed in the component

`Parent.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>Text Input</h2>
        <input v-model="input1"> {{ input1 }}

        <h2>Multi Checkbox</h2>
        <input type="checkbox" id="jack" value="Jack" v-model="input2">
        <label for="jack">Jack</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="john" value="John" v-model="input2">
        <label for="john">John</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="mike" value="Mike" v-model="input2">
        <label for="mike">Mike</label>
        <p>Checked names: <pre>{{ input2 }}</pre></p>

        <h2>Radio</h2>
        <input type="radio" id="one" value="One" v-model="input3">
        <label for="one">One</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" id="two" value="Two" v-model="input3">
        <label for="two">Two</label>
        <br>
        <span>Picked: {{ input3 }}</span>
        <h2>new stuff</h2>
        <button @click="getData()">Push Me</button>

        <p> The data is changing here: {{ allInputs }} </p>

        <child :all-inputs="allInputs"></child >
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import child  from './child .vue';

export default{
    components: {
        'child':child 
    },
    data(){
        return{
            input1: '',
            input2: [],
            input3: '',
            allInputs: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getData(){
            this.allInputs = {
                input1: this.input1,
                input2: this.input2,
                input3: this.input3
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

But when I pass the data from the parent to a child, the data is not displayed on update:

`Child.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div class="all-inputs">
        <p>{{ passedData }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    props: ["allInputs"],
    data (){
        return{
            passedData: this.allInputs
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

Comment: @Vucko would it be better if I just pass all of the data to the child, instead of having a button to update the data?

Comment: If you using vue 2 its not working because with this assignment you lost the reactivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your child is not updating because you are using the local data property `passedData` in the template, not the props `allInputs`. If you will console the `allInputs` somewhere in the child component you will see that it is updating whenever the parent updates but as you are not using the prop directly so you are not seeing its reactivity. So, use props in your template instead of local data property, like this-

```
<p>{{ allInputs }}</p>
```

Not this-

```
<p>{{ passedData }}</p>
```

The approach you are trying to do is used when the child component wants to update the props passed by the parent but mutating parent props is erroneous because a child should not mutate (modify) the parent's state. So we usually assign props to a local data property and then mutate that data property, not props (same as you are doing). You can read more about this concept [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#one-way-data-flow).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having `passedData` in your template like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="all-inputs">
        <p>{{ passedData }}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

Change it to:

```
<template>
    <div class="all-inputs">
        <p>{{ allInputs }}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```